# What is the purpose of the [valid-html] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The purpose of the [html-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-validation) and [html5-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-validation) tags are clear. They are for questions about "client-side form validation in browsers" and "constraint-validation engine in HTML5 which allows easy validation of forms".

So when looking to tag a question about what constitutes valid HTML structure/syntax, I discovered the [valid-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valid-html) tag. However, there are only 14 questions with [valid-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valid-html) and there is no tag info.

I see that most of the "valid HTML structure/syntax/markup" related questions are tagged [w3c-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-validation) and in some cases [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml). Therefore, is the [valid-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valid-html) tag needed, and should I suggest tag info? Should a synonym be added for [w3c-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-validation)?

Comment: I don't think we need this tag. I went through all posts, checked all of them and edited. The tag doesn't add value to the question. It should be removed by the system soon. Also, the name "valid-html" by itself doesn't seem right. Maybe something like "html-validation" makes more sense.

Comment: @Maroun *Maybe something like "html-validation" makes more sense*.. but, doesn't the existing [tag:html-validation] seem appropriate for its' purpose (client-side form validation in browsers), and not for valid HTML structure/syntax?

Comment: I didn't even know it exists. In my opinion, there's no need at all to have a tag specifically for validating HTML structure. Having "html" alone, with the question itself, should be enough.

Comment: I think `html-validation` is quite ambiguous in itself, maybe it should just have been `html5-validation-api` and `w3c-validation`?

Comment: @ivarni w3c isn't the only one validating html5 spec, nor does it is the only api.

Comment: @Braiam Fair enough, I just think `html-validation` can easily be interpreted as both the "new" API for constraint validation *and* the act of validating HTML structure. Maybe that can just be solved with a tag description though.

Comment: Never mind, [it already does](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html-validation/info). Ignore me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, we don't need a [valid-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valid-html) tag. Markup validation issues are covered by [w3c-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/w3c-validation) (whether or not you choose to validate against W3C HTML5 out of principle), and even then there isn't a pressing need to include that tag even when someone is asking a question about markup validation.

Even the WHATWG accepts "HTML5" as a buzzword for the current generation of HTML, so between [html-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-validation) and [html5-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-validation) I would choose the latter as it's far more widely recognized to mean "the validation feature set and API of HTML5".

Comment: Put another way, we also don't need a `valid-css` tag, nor a `valid-xml`, `valid-java`, etc. Any tag for a language or format is broad enough to encompass questions regarding what constitutes valid syntax, imo.